# Unpause application in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, process, virtual-memory

I tried parsing a gigantic XML file and I ended up running out of virtual memory. The OS put all my applications on pause and gave me a screen to shutdown applications to free more space. I killed the XML parsing application and now have tons of space but I can't resume my paused applications anymore. What should I do?

Comment: much related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/226201/all-applications-got-paused-after-disk-space-usage-got-near-99-and-back-to-norm

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Find your paused app's process ID (using either Activity Monitor or ps -ax | grep ), then issue it the CONT signal using "kill" in the terminal (don't worry, "kill" is misnamed, it just sends a signal to an app - it's called kill because the default signal is QUIT)

```
% ps -ax | grep Safari
  461 ??        61:22.30 /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari -psn_0_180268
% kill -CONT 461
%
```

Comment: thanks for the hint! but it lead me into this similar solution: simply using `killall -CONT Safari` - feel free to add this to your answer! ;)

Comment: Is there an easy way to find out which processes have been paused?

Comment: Any advice on a situation where Terminal is in paused state?

Comment: @Jawa - open iterm if you have it, or X11, to get at the terminal some other way.  Alternatively, ssh in from another machine.  But these are workarounds, I'd love a better solution

Answer (score 9):

To un-pause all applications, run this command in Terminal:

```
pkill -CONT -u $UID
```

or (as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/q/1076932/87805)):

```
kill -CONT -1
```

---

To un-pause the specific app (such as Chrome), try:

```
kill -CONT $(pgrep Chrome)
```

---

Consider adding the following alias into your *rc* files (such as `~/.bashrc`):

```
alias unpause="pkill -CONT -u $UID"
```

So next time you may just run: `unpause`.

Comment: or just use `kill -CONT -1` as explained here: https://superuser.com/questions/1076932/un-pause-all-paused-processes-osx