# Un-pause all paused processes osx

Tags: macos, kill

In osx it is possible to un-pause a single process with the command:

```
kill -CONT 1234
```

Where 1234 is the process id.

Is there a way to un-pause every paused process on the machine?

---

Why: There is a undocumented feature (aka. bug) of osx where sometimes multiple applications are paused at the same time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
kill -CONT -1
```

should send the signal to all processes
that you have permission to send signals to (with a few exceptions):

> If the user has super-user privileges,
>   the signal is sent to all processes excluding system processes
>   (with P_SYSTEM flag set), process with ID 1 (usually init(8)),
>   and the process sending the signal. 
>   If the user is not the super user,
>   the signal is sent to all processes
>   with the same uid as the user excluding the process sending the signal. 
>   No error is returned if any process could be signaled.
>                                   <sub>— from [kill(2)](http://man.cx/kill(2))</sub>